# Why isn't a semicolon accepted after then?

Tags: shell

I'm new to shell programming, and noticed that the following is accepted:

```
if [ $table = "Session" ]; then
continue; fi
```

And so is the following:

```
if [ $table = "Session" ]; then continue; fi
```

While the following produces a syntax error:

```
if [ $table = "Session" ]; then; continue; fi
```

Why is the `then` keyword different from the others?

Comment: This looks like a problem in the shell to me. Replace the `;` with a `newline` and it works. Otoh, omit the line with `continue` and you get the error. Read the source, Ben.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `then` is neither a command nor a shell builtin, but actually a part of the `if` syntax. From `man bash`:

```
   if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
          The  if  list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the then
          list is executed.  Otherwise, each  elif  list  is  executed  in
          turn,  and  if  its  exit status is zero, the corresponding then
          list is executed and the command completes.  Otherwise, the else
          list  is executed, if present.  The exit status is the exit sta‐
          tus of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested
          true.
```

So this:

> ```
> if [ $table = "Session" ]; then continue; fi
> ```

works because both `[ $table = "Session" ]` and `continue` are commands that can stand alone; they make up the respective `list` part of the `if` command. Just paste those into an interactive shell and you will see that they won't cause any syntax errors:

```
martin@martin:~$ export table=test
martin@martin:~$ [ $table = "Session" ]
martin@martin:~$ continue
bash: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

On the other hand, `then` is not a real command that can stand on its own:

```
martin@martin:~$ then
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

So in the first two examples, you're using `if` just like the man page describes it:

```
if list; then list; fi
```

But if you put a `;` behind `then`, `bash` will see this as a syntax error. Admittedly, shell syntax can seem quite confusing sometimes, especially when you're just getting into it. I remember being very confused about the fact that it requires spaces around `[` and `]`, but once you realize that `[` is actually a command or shell builtin, it's comprehensible. :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to put a semicolon after a command. `[ … ]` is a command, as is `continue`. On the other hand, `if`, `then` and `fi` are not commands: they are reserved words.

`if` looks like a command, but that's because it's almost always followed by exactly one command. It is valid to write

```
if print_table_value >foo; [ "$(cat foo)" = "Session" ]; then …
```

which can also be presented in a number of ways such as

```
if
  print_table_value >foo
  [ "$(cat foo)" = "Session" ]
then
…
```

The general syntax of a conditional command is

```
if compound-list then compound-list
(elif compound-list then compound-list)*
(else compound-list then compound-list)?
fi
```

where

- The line breaks are for readability only.
- A *compound-list* is a list of commands, each terminated by a `;` or newline.
- (…)<sup>?</sup> indicates an optional part and (…)<sup>*</sup> indicates a part that can be repeated 0, 1 or many times.

Keywords are only recognized as such at the beginning of a command.

A conditional command has to end with the keyword `fi`. This does not remove the need to follow it by an operator if some other command appears after it; for example, if the conditional is to be followed by another command, then there needs to be a `;` or newline in between; if the conditional is to be executed in the background, then it needs to be followed by `&`, etc.